# Rails server exits on using Process lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) gem for building a api. I am trying to use ruby's [Process](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Process.html) lib in the controller to fiddle with media players like this.

```
def playNext
    Process.exec('musique --next')
end
```

But as soon the command executes rails server exits. I might be doing a completely stupid thing.

What's going wrong? Is there something wrong with the approach(maybe stupid one) i am using?

Comment: Can you see any error and stack trace? That would help.

Comment: There's no stack trace or at least i couldn't find one.  Console exits immediately without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process::exec` [replaces the current process with the spawned process](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-exec). Once the spawned process exits, there is no more parent process to resume running.

Instead, use `Process::spawn`.

To demonstrate:

```
puts "About to spawn"
Process.spawn("ls -l | wc -l")
puts "Finished listing via spawn"

puts "About to exec"
exec("ls -l | wc -l")
puts "Finished listing via exec"
```

And the output:

```
About to spawn
Finished listing via spawn
About to exec
777
777
```

The final `puts` is never called, because `exec` effectively terminates the Ruby process and replaces it with the subprocess.